# Delete a element in multi nested JSON using javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to delete any JSON element by using their key. For example,

This is my JSON data:

```
{
  "CreateprivateNetwork": {
    "description": "Creatinganetwork.",
    "input": {
        "body": {
            "network": {
                "name": "$.networkname",
                "admin_state_up": "sdfdsf"
            }
        }
    },
    "action": "neutron.create_network",
    "publish": {}
  }
}
```

I want to delete the element "name" from this JSON

PATH TO DELETE : "CreateprivateNetwork.input.body.network.name".

Please help me to solve this problem.

**Note**: This path may change Dynamically. So I have to delete any elements from dynamic JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse` to remove keys that you don't need

```js
function format(json_string, key_to_skip) {
    return JSON.parse(json_string, function (key, value) {
        if (key !== key_to_skip) {
            return value;
        }
    });    
}

var json = {
    "CreateprivateNetwork": {
        "description": "Creatinganetwork.",
        "input": {
            "body": {
                "network": {
                    "name": "$.networkname",
                    "admin_state_up": "sdfdsf"
                }
            }
        },
        "action": "neutron.create_network",
        "publish": {}
    }
};

alert(JSON.stringify(format(JSON.stringify(json), 'name')));
```

Comment: Thank you so much its working fine.... But it removes only the key value ...For example , key_to_skip = 'name' means i want to delete the "name" and its value "$.networkname".

Comment: "key_to_skip" will automatically remove it's value too. A "key" should be present to hold it's "value" right ? :)

Comment: Ya thank you....I slightly modify your code...Now everything is properly working ....Thank you so much